# Gmail API to access, read/modify the delegated emails or shared gmail using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail-api

I can read/modify gmails from my own Gmail account via Gmail API using its credentials.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
```

But now, IT operation provide me a **shared Gmail or delegate Gmail account. So I want to access, read/modify from that delegate email**.

How can I access and read delegate gmail using Gmail API?
Is there any example?

Most of the code in Gmail API sites are in Python and Java which I don't understand.

please shed some lights.

What I have tried:

I can access, read my own mail by using Gmail API -

```
private static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify };
private UserCredential _credential;
private string credPath = "token.json";

 public UserCredential GetCredential()
 {
 using (var stream =
  new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
         _credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
             GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
             Scopes,
             "user",
             CancellationToken.None,
             new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
     }

     return _credential;
 }
```

---

```
GmailCredentials Info = new GmailCredentials();
      private static string ApplicationName = "xxxxx";
      
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(),
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            
            UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
            request.Q = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filter"];
            request.MaxResults = Convert.ToInt64(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["maxCount"]);  //5;
            messages = request.Execute().Messages;
            List<string> lstRemove = new List<string>() { "UNREAD" };
            
            /// Read the individual message and output as List<Email>
            for (int index = 0; index < messages.Count; index++)
            {
            //... Do the code...
            }
```

Comment: Have you considered connecting to Gmail using MailKit?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't use MailKit. But I can use only Gmail API to read the emails. I  can access and read my own account via Gmail API, but I don't know how to access delegate or shared email from Gmail API using C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail API does not work with delegated mailboxes. Only the user's own mailbox is accessible. To access all user mail in the G Suite domain, try using service account and [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).